# Flutter needs an extra tap to hide all overlays on Android

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I basically want to toggle the top UI overlay, but for some reason the bottom ui bar shows up too for a third unimplemented tap.

In the video i tapped 2 x 3 times to demonstrate the issue.

Please advise.

```
bool visible = false;

toggleSettings() {
   if (!visible) {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
   } else {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
   }

   visible = !visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: when you calling this function.

Comment: on tap, and as you can see it should just toggle the overlay, but it needs one extra tap for some reason